# Re-use computed text on HTML side in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to calculate some `{{interpolated | filtered | complicated }} {{text expression}}` in the HTML, and then use it twice in the HTML (without duplicating "code" by using the actual expression twice).

I might calculate the expression's result in a helper function in the controller using `$interpolate` (I *think* that will work?) and then call the helper function twice. But I think the complicated text expression really belongs in the HTML file.

Is there a way in Angular to say, in the HTML file, "Set this temp variable to this (interpolated) string, and then interpolate that variable *here* and also *there*"?

Comment: Isn't this similar to the examples where a boolean value is updated on an ng-click event `ng-click="updated = !updated"` and the code watching updates; something is shown or hidden?  In essence, changing a variable on $scope.

Comment: I wasn't trying to change a variable on $scope... The answer I approved, below, is exactly what I was looking for. I just hadn't realized I could execute arbitrary code inside {{ }} and have the variable remembered between {{ }}. If that variable is actually stored in $scope (and that's why it's remembered) then I'll just have to avoid name conflicts; not a big deal.

Comment: I would check, but I do believe it is creating the variable on $scope ... I think we're all on the same page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this both in the JS controller and in the html template, I assume you're looking for the latter.

```
{{temp = (interpolated | filtered | complicated) }}


{{temp}}
```

Comment: I hadn't realized you could do that. Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use template filters for this.  Create your own variable with the processed data, and reference that from multiple places in the template.